# Scheme Function that can select nth term of a list

Tags: lisp, scheme

So here i have a couple of defined list that i would like to use:

```
(DEFINE list0 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'j) )
(DEFINE list1 (LIST 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g) )
(DEFINE list2 (LIST 's 't 'u 'v 'w 'x 'y 'z) )
(DEFINE list3 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'l 'k 'j) )
(DEFINE list4 (LIST 'n 'o 'p 'q 'q 'p 'o 'n) )
(DEFINE list5 '( (a b) c (d e d) c (a b) ) )
(DEFINE list6 '( (h i) (j k) l (m n) ) )
(DEFINE list7 (f (a b) c (d e d) (b a) f) )
```

what i would like to do is create a recursive function for a 'middle' function that would do as such:

MIDDLE:
(middle 1st) should return a one-element list consisting of just the middle element of the 1st [or return the empty list if there were an even number of elements in 1st]. That is,

`(middle '(a b c d e f g) )`
should/would return:
`(d)`

`(middle '(s t u v w x y z) )`
should/would return the empty string.

`(middle '( (a b) c (d e d) c (b a) ) )`
should/would return:
`( (d e d) )`
Note that `( (d e d) )` is a list containing the thing that was in the middle, which happened to itself be a list.

I think that i have to break it into two problems.
First is that i need a function that can select the nth term of a list. which i little knowledge on creating it.
Second you need a functions to determine the position of the middle term and if there exists a middle term. (which also i have minimum knowledge on how to create it.
Then

```
(define middle
    (lambda (L)
        (if (middle? L)
        (nth-term (middle L) L)
        '())))
```

Here is my evens function that i would like to know if there might be an easier way to go about it:

```
(define evens
    (lambda (L)
    (if (or (NULL? (cddr L)))
        '()
    (cons (cadr L) (evens (cddr L))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be improved a bit as follows:

```
(define (middle lst)
  (let ((len (length lst)))
    (if (even? len)
        '()
        (list (list-ref lst (quotient len 2))))))
```

Notice that there was a simpler way to obtain the index of the middle element.

Comment: an `nth` function would be more versatile than a `middle` function.

Comment: @AlexejMagura the question is about `middle`, and anyway it uses `list-ref` - the "nth" function.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use the length function to get the length of the list, then make sure the length is an not an even number (and if it is, to return an empty list). Once we know that the length is odd, return the element of the list that is half the length of the list minus one. The result is the middle of the list. Here is what the code actually looks like:

```
    (define (middle lis)
      (let ((list-length (length lis)))
        (if (even? list-length)
            '()
            (list (list-ref lis (/ (- list-length 1) 2))))))
```

To answer the question in your subject line, you get the nth item of a list with the list-ref procedure, like so:

```
    > (list-ref '(a b c d) 2)
    'c
```

If there's anything you are still confused about, let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: Thank you, i actually can see how everything falls in place after your explanation.

Comment: One thing i see that you say that there is an easier way to create a middle function, do you think that what i have for my evens function is good or might there also be an easier way for this, i posted it in the previous question towards the end.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious method (compute the length; divide by two; seek through the list) requires two passes through the list.

Here is an alternative that requires only one pass:

```
(define (middle lst)
  (letrec
    ((middle-odd
       (lambda (x y) (if (null? x) (list (car y)) (middle-even (cdr x) (cdr y)))))
     (middle-even
       (lambda (x y) (if (null? x) '() (middle-odd (cdr x) y)))))
    (middle-even lst lst)))
```